# when to define a ControlTemplate inside a style as a resource?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, controltemplate

i've seen that is common to put a `ControlTemplate` inside a `Style` as in the following example

```xml
<Style x:Key="roundbutton" TargetType="Button">
  <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
        <Grid>
            <Ellipse Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

instead of just defininig the control template as a resurce

```xml
<ControlTemplate x:Key="roundbutton" TargetType="Button">
    <Grid>
        <Ellipse Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

What are the advantages of defining the `ControlTemplate` inside a `Style`?

Comment: A Style and a ControlTemplate are two different things. You can't say that a "ControlTemplate is defined as Style". In contrast to a ControlTemplate, a Style resource could be declared without `x:Key`, so that it would automatically be applied to all instances of the TargetType.

Comment: You should ask "what are the advantages of assigning the template from as Style compared to assigning the template directly from the control?" - the answer to which is nothing. There are no significant differences.